How to fix parameter locally for iterating recursion equations
The following is a simplified version of a more detailed problem.
I have two coupled recursion equations of two variables, x and y. One equation also depends on a parameter, c:
F[x_, y_] := x + y - c
G[x_, y_] := y/x

Starting with initial conditions, {x[0],y[0]}, I want to iterate these equations to convergence (in the real problem they always converge) for each of a range of c values (c=1, c=2, c=3, .... c=cmax). So, the result I want is a list of ordered pairs, {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},....}, where {xi,yi} are the values that x and y converge to for c=i.
If I globally define e.g. c=1 and assume that e.g. {x[0],y[0]}={3,2}, I can get a result like this (assuming convergence within 10 iterations just for demonstration):
c = 1;
F[x_, y_] := x + y - c
G[x_, y_] := y/x
Iter[x_, y_] := Nest[Apply[Through[{F, G}@##] &], {x, y}, 10] // N
Iter[3, 2]

Presumably I could use this approach in a For loop over c values to get what I want but I would rather write a function that can be threaded over a list of c values. The idea is that for each c value input, the function iterates x and y to convergence, so x and y vary while c is constant. I tried to do this by locally defining c using With, like so:
F[x_, y_] := x + y - c
G[x_, y_] := y/x
Iter[i_, x_, y_] := 
 With[{c = i}, Nest[Apply[Through[{F, G}@##] &], {x, y}, 10] // N]
Iter[1, 3, 2]

but for some reason this doesn't set c to i. Using Module instead of With doesn't work either. Is there a better approach to this kind of thing or maybe just some syntactic error here?

One (less desirable) fix is to use Block rather than With:
F[x_, y_] := x + y - c;
G[x_, y_] := y/x;
Iter[i_, x_, y_] := Block[{c = i}, Nest[Apply[Through[{F, G}@##] &], {x, y}, 10] // N];

(This is less desirable because it's still vulnerable to side effects.)
A more fully functional style would be to parameterize F:
F[c_][x_, y_] := x + y - c;
G[x_, y_] := y/x;
Iter[c_, x_, y_] := Nest[Apply[Through[{F[c], G}@##] &], {x, y}, 10] // N;

(Also, side note, you might like Comap or ComapApply--it would simplify your Apply+Through strategy.)

Probably this:
Iter[i_, x_, y_] := With[{c = i},
  F[x1_, y1_] := x1 + y1 - c;
  G[x1_, y1_] := y1/x1; 
  Nest[Apply[Through[{F, G}@##] &], {x, y}, 10] // N]
Iter[1, 3, 2]


{-4.13656, 0.0134278}

